# Can first page and second page have different header and footer?

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs, puppeteer

I'm using **puppeteer** with **node.js** to render a pdf report. I have a problem. I have to apply different **header/footer** for the first page(intro page) and second page. Is that possible to do it. I was using **phantomjs** to render pdf. Somehow i managed to do that in phantomjs and don't know about puppeteer. Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you manage to do it in PhantomJS and what problems are you having in doing the same in Puppeteer?

Comment: In phantomjs header and footer are passed as string function with two parameters**(pageNumber,numberOfPages)**. I will handled a condition with the help of **pageNumber**. If 1st page, apply certain property and  for the rest, apply certain property likewise. But in puppeteer, header/footer are passed as **HTML** directly. So i don't know how to differentiate it.

Comment: @laggingreflex Any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: hi, did u solve this?

Comment: @Akza No. <script> is currently not supported in puppeteer. Without that, it is not possible to do.

Comment: so, you stick with phantomjs? or, what u do as the workaround?

Comment: I'm using puppeteer. But for my use case, I started drawing my own header and footer with the help of evaluate. I will set the page margin for pagepdf() to 0px. I will calculate the every page height and I will add the header and footer for each page. It won't be applicable for all use-cases. Luckily for me it works.